# My layout doesn't allow me to show xlab and ylab

Tags: r, text, layout, par

It looks like something simple I am missing but have no idea how to deal with this.

So I used a **layout()** function and I managed to get the layout as I wanted as below picture. Iris data was used in my coding.

[image]

**Problem is**,  it does not show me the x label and y label on the output when I use plot() functions after this. And xaxis and yaxis for plot() looks overlapping. I am not sure how to deal with this problem.

There was no problem for x and y labelling before introducing plot.new() and par() to set up the main name of my diagram. (i.e. before I use the code from plot.new() to title(), xlab and ylab were shown)

I used 6 different plots in my original code, including, the plot.new() for title(), but I omitted the rest of them for convenience

[image]

Here is my code below,

```
x <- iris$Sepal.Length
y <- iris$Species


x_min <- min(iris$Sepal.Length)
x_max <- max(iris$Sepal.Length)
y_min <- min(iris$Sepal.Width)
y_max <- max(iris$Sepal.Width)


layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,
            2,2,3,3,4,4,
            5,5,5,6,6,6), nc=6, byrow = TRUE), heights=c(lcm(1),1,1,1,1))
layout.show(6)
par("mar"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
text(x=0.5,y=0.5,"scatter and density plots for Sepal and Length and Sepal Width" ,font=2, cex=1.5)
plot(...)
```

Comment: (1) `par(mar=...)` takes a vectof of 4, not 6. (2) You explicitly set the margins to "1" which, in the case of base R plots, typically means the default axis numbers are hidden. (3) If after changing `mar=` you still have questions, it would really help to have some reproducible code (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/).

Comment: If par() function hides the axis, what is the alternative way to use this layout? Because if I leave out par() function, the error says "figure margins are too large"

Comment: Do you get the "too large" error on all plots or just the top (`text(...)`) plot? That's the only one that (from the image) I would expect that behavior. Realize that `par(mar=)` is per "pane", so-to-speak, so your plots 2-6 can have different margins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xlab` and `ylab` arguments in `title`. However, the way you have constructed the plot means that when you reset `par` at the end, these are drawn off the page due ti their position relative to your custom axis. If you simply leave `par` alone, you get:

```r
den1 = density(CDE1$V1)
den2 = density(CDE1$V2)

col1 = hsv(h = 0.65, s = 0.6, v = 0.8, alpha = 0.5)
col2 = hsv(h = 0.85, s = 0.6, v = 0.8, alpha = 0.5)

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(25,65), ylim = c(0, 0.14))
axis(side = 1, pos = 0, at = seq(from = 25, to = 65, by = 5), col = "gray20", 
     lwd.ticks = 0.25, cex.axis = 1, col.axis = "gray20", lwd = 1.5)
axis(side = 2, pos = 25, at = seq(from = 0, to = 0.14, by = 0.02), 
     col = "gray20", las = 2, lwd.ticks = 0.5, cex.axis = 1, 
     col.axis = "gray20", lwd = 1.5)
polygon(den1$x, den1$y, col = col1, border ="black",lwd = 2)
polygon(den2$x, den2$y, col = col2, border ="black",lwd = 2)
text(52, 0.10, labels ="CDET", col =col1, cex = 1.25,font=2)
text(35, 0.03, labels ="SDFT", col =col2, cex = 1.25,font=2)

title(main = "Gestational Day 100/283", 
      xlab = "Fibril Diameter (nm)",
      ylab = "density")
```

[image]

Of course, you could get a similar plot with less code and much easier adjustments using `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(CDE1, 1:2), aes(value, fill = name)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(col1, col2), labels = c("CDET", "SDFT")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(25, 65, 5), limits = c(25, 65)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 0.14, 0.02), limits = c(0, 0.14)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  labs(title = "Gestational Day 100/283", x = "Fibril Diameter (nm)", 
       fill = NULL) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

### [image]

**Data used**

Obviously, we don't have your data, so I had to create a reproducible approximation:

```r
set.seed(123)
CDE1 <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(20, 47.5, 4), V2 = rnorm(20, 44, 5))
```